# Chrome Developer Tools highlighting issue

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I recently found myself not able to use Google Chrome’s developer tools easily, since the Inspect feature doesn’t anymore highlight elements under cursor while I move it around the page (I have to click the element in order to jump to its node). In addition, the mouse cursor doesn’t even change to “type” or “pointer” styles when moved around the page while the developer tools are open.

It works as expected in the Incognito mode though, so at first I suspected that it’s an issue with some of my extensions. However, disabling them all (first individually, then all at once) didn’t prove this to be the case.

Has anyone else experienced this or could suggest a solution? I’ll also add that none of experimental flags in about:flags are turned on, and this problem occurs on every page I open, not just specific ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the *Emulate Touch Events* setting that was left enabled under *Settings → Overrides*. I’m pretty sure that it used to work with this setting on previously, so maybe one of the recent updates has changed that. Anyway, turning that off fixes the problem for me.